# How can I replicate a block of text with a pattern replaced?

Tags: vimscript

I have a bunch of blocks of text across multiple files that reference a common symbol (a number). I need to create several copies of this with the symbol replaced with different values of the number. Example:

```
fun myGreatFunction4() {
  // this is my great function number 4
  ...
}

fun otherStuff() {
}
```

I need to create versions 5 through n of `myGreatFunction4()`, and I have many such text blocks that need replicated n-4 times with the same modification. I was imagining navigating to each such block, selecting it, and running a command to replicate and replace each time. It would do something like accept a range or list of replacements, and make a copy of the block for each element, replacing each number with the new one. That would work fine for this situation, but I'm not sure how best to make it happen. Any suggestions?

I'm tagging as vimscript, but I'm fine with other solutions.

Comment: It would help if you provide more lines in Example plus desired output...

Comment: https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/plugin/replacme.vim If something like this would do I can add an answer

Comment: Maybe I'm being naive but the usual way to have a function that differs in nothing but one number would be to write one function and pass that number as an argument.

Comment: @Friedrich yes, that is reasonable, but I would have dozens of those functions to write for the various blocks of text to update since the content for each one is different.

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble thanks for the link! I ended up doing this a bit more manually for the current task at hand but I'll save your link for the future as an examle when I need to do something similar.